Non reflexivity of $W^{1,1}$ and $W^{1,\infty}$
I want to prove that given an open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n,\ W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ and $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ are not reflexive.
Let's start with $n=1$ and $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$. For the Eberlein–Šmulian theorem we should find a bounded sequence such that it doesn't have a weakly convergent subsequence, in this answer they follow this approach, but more importantly in the comment under the answer @Jochen Glueck says:\begin{align}
W^{1,1}(0,1) \cong \mathbb{R} \times L^1(0,1),
\end{align}
so $W^{1,1}(0,1)$ is not reflexive and being an isomorphic copy of a closed subspace of $W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R})$ we find that also the latter one is not reflexive. Can we generalize this to higher dimension? It's true that $W^{1,1}(\Omega) \cong \mathbb{R}^n \times L^1(\Omega)$ if
$\Omega$ is an open bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$?
For $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ and any $n$, I would like to find a closed subspace of $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ such that it is isomoprhic to $L^\infty(0,1)$, and then we can conclude thanks to the non-refelxivity of $L^\infty$. I know that such subspace exists but I don't know how to explicitly find it.
Thanks in advance.

We first start with $W^{1,\infty}(0,1)$. Define a map $F:\mathbb{R}\times L^\infty(0,1)\rightarrow W^{1,\infty}(0,1)$ as follows:
$$F(c,f)=\int_0^xf(t)dt+c$$
It is easy to see that this is a bounded operator. Actually this map defines an isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}\times L^p(0,1)$ and $W^{1,p}(0,1)$ for any $1\leq p\leq \infty$. The inverse is given by $F^{-1}(f)=(f^*(0),f')$, where $f^*$ is the unique continuous representative of $f$ and $f'$ is just the weak derivative (to see that this is indeed the inverse, you can use Lemma 8.2 of the functional analysis textbook written by Brezis). We can then conclude that $W^{1,\infty}(0,1)$ is not reflexive because it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\times L^\infty(0,1)$, which contains a copy of the nonreflexive space $L^\infty(0,1)$.
Let's now consider the higher dimensional case. I first want to define a map $G:W^{1,p}(0,1)\rightarrow W^{1,p}(\Pi_{i=1}^n(0,1))$, where $p=1$ or $p=\infty$:
$$G(f)(x_1,\cdots, x_n)=f(x_1)$$
Basically we project the cube to its first coordinate and then compose it with $f$. $D_1G(f)=f'$ and $D_iG(f)=0$ for $i\ne 1$, which implies that $G$ is a bounded operator. Since $G$ is injective, $ W^{1,p}(\Pi_{i=1}^n(0,1))$ is not reflexive as it contains a (closed) copy of $ W^{1,p}(0,1)$.
For a domain $\Omega$ that is nice enough (e.g. with smooth boundary/has the extension property), $\Omega$ contains a cube $Q:=\Pi_{i=1}^n(a_i,b_i)$ and every Sobolev function defined on $Q$ can be extended to a Soboleve function on $\Omega$. Denote the extension operator by $P$. $P\circ G$ is an injective bounded operator from $W^{1,p}(a_1,b_1)$ to $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, which implies that $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is not reflexive.
